# 400 Bad Request error when trying to write to S3 from an EMR 7.0.0 cluster

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have an Spark application working flawlessly using emr-5.29.0 and Spark 2.4.4. This app writes to  S3 using Spark SQL like this

```
df
    .repartition($"year", $"month", $"day")
    .write
    .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
    .mode(saveMode)
    .parquet(path)
```

The path is a `s3a` valid one.

My problem comes when I upgraded to Spark 3.5.0 and emr-7.0.0. My jar is aligned with the provided dependencies provided by AWS like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "3.4.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "3.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.5.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.5.0",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.12.569",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.3.6",
)
```

But when executing the corresponding step in the EMR 7.0.0 the job fails when trying to write in S3:

```
xception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: getFileStatus on s3a://x-bucket/raw/xxx: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxx, Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxx):null: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxx, Extended Request ID: gxxxxxxx)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3987)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$exists$34(S3AFileSystem.java:4889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.invokeTrackingDuration(IOStatisticsBinding.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.lambda$trackDurationOfOperation$5(IOStatisticsBinding.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.trackDuration(IOStatisticsBinding.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.trackDurationAndSpan(S3AFileSystem.java:2654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.trackDurationAndSpan(S3AFileSystem.java:2673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:4887)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:559)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$9(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$8(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:479)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:792)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.utils.ParquetEventWriter.write(ParquetEventWriter.scala:13)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp$.getKafkaEventsByTopicBetweenTimestamps(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala:182)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp$.$anonfun$processKafkaEventsInBetweenDates$1(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala:130)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp$.$anonfun$processKafkaEventsInBetweenDates$1$adapted(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp$.processKafkaEventsInBetweenDates(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala:120)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp$.main(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala:75)
    at com.d.data.pipeline.batch.io.KafkaToS3SparkApp.main(KafkaToS3SparkApp.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1075)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1176)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: JB2KN3QAMSCD504T, Extended Request ID: gcvyho7fncYObCK92QMAPIeanVQ8ShjPOoJNBE3dewSr18ZRBczNmIY00+sDe6lFjfjv+jShI7Q=)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:95)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:270)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:38)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:72)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:78)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:40)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:55)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptMetricCollectionStage.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:81)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:50)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:32)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:198)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:171)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.headObject(DefaultS3Client.java:5495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$getObjectMetadata$8(S3AFileSystem.java:2847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2835)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3965)
```

I'm using the `eu-west-1` region.

The EMR is using the `EMR_DefaultRole_v2` role, also to try to remove authz from the equation I added the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to the role but no dice, the error is still there.

I've also found this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-access-grants.html but I don't know if that could be the answer given that I just set full access for S3.

Also if you know how to debug / check logs for the request id's that the s3 library throws it would be awesome :)

I've expected that the job will behave exactly like the emr-5.29.0 and Spark 2.4.4 one, but the error thrown is super opaque and difficult to debug.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by explicitly set the s3a endpoint like this:

```
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Hope it's helpful for other ppl :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I moved my spark application to EMR 7.0.0 from EMR 6.8.0. And the S3 bucket that I was trying to access belonged to the same region as my EMR cluster, i.e. us-west-2.
The solution that worked for me is replacing "s3a://" with "s3://".

According to AWS Support team,
"With newer versions of EMR, it is recommended to use 's3://' instead of 's3a://' or 's3n://' for better performance, security and reliability..
s3a:// uses open source implementation while s3:// uses AWS EMRFS implementation, we always recommend using s3:// on EMR."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-signing.html

Comment: ` s3a seems to push malformed authorized headers`. If it did i'd be fielding a lot of support calls. I'd say "client is talking to a region where the bucket isn't, or to us-east-1 to a bucket in a aws region which only accepts v4 signing. but eu-west-1 (ireland) isn't that. see https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Comment: note: EMR s3 is their own s3 connector, if AWS support say "use this" then go with it as it is the only one they support. but s3a works for everyone else, so don't blame our code.

Comment: @stevel I guess AWS support said this with respect to my case. But as it can be misleading to others, I have edited my answer to avoid any confusion.